# Google visualization percent issue

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

i wasnt able to recreate it in jsfiddle so this is all i could provide. I was hoping someone to contact me as im still new and the one who made this code passed away from covid.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgJJ3.jpg

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback();

function load_monthwise_data(pos, title)
{
    var temp_title = title + ' '+pos+'';
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{pos:pos},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success:function(data)
        {
            drawMonthwiseChart(data, temp_title);
        }
    });
function drawMonthwiseChart(chart_data, chart_main_title)
{
    var jsonData = chart_data;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Nama Calon');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Jumlah Undian');
    $.each(jsonData, function(i, jsonData){
        var name = jsonData.name;
        var total = parseFloat($.trim(jsonData.total));
        data.addRows([[name, total]]);
    });
    var options = {
        title:chart_main_title,
        hAxis: {
            title: "Nama Calon"
        },
        vAxis: { 
            title: 'Jumlah Undian', 
            format: '#%'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_area'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

the percentage value goes beyond 100% and the percentage relates to the total value

Comment: @AlonEitan ive added the code that my late friend did and even i dont know whats in there

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to provide some assistance but, I will try. Below you will find a link that describe using google virtualization api and a few use cases.

This is me speculating but, it looks like Bar graph values are setting the bar size or length dynamically. So, if you have a lot of data the bar would be larger in size respectively.

```
function drawMonthwiseChart(chart_data, chart_main_title){
  var j = 0;
  var jsonData = chart_data;
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Nama Calon');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Jumlah Undian');
  $.each(jsonData, function(i, jsonData){
    var name = jsonData.name;
    // looks like the issue's coming from here (the total value)
    //var total = parseFloat($.trim(jsonData.total));
    //data.addRows([[name, total]]);
   // Use this, if the total is less than or equal to 100 append data
     var total = parseFloat($.trim(jsonData.total));
     j += 1; // looks like it's counting the number of instead of percentages
     if(j <= 100){
       data.addRows([[name, total]]);
     }
  });
  var options = {
    title:chart_main_title,
      hAxis: {
        title: "Nama Calon"
      },
      vAxis: { 
        title: 'Jumlah Undian', 
        format: '#%'
      }
  };

  var chart = new 
  google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_area'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**UPDATE** Looks like it's the looping, and number of records (data) is setting the chart size.

Resource:

- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

Comment: ive added the code that my late friend made and even i dont understand whats in there.

Comment: The result is the still the same the 2 total value still ends up becoming 200%

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my solution. I think this should fix the problem.